# Arrays.sort is not working as intended

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, char

I'm supposed to sort a char array and print it in descending order. Should be simple, however, I'm not getting the output I want. All solutions around the internet tells me Arrays.sort is okay to use, but am I supposed to use another method? Or am I overlooking something?

```
public class mainClassTextFile {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    FileReader fileReader = new FileReader("file.txt");    
    String fileContents = "";
    int i;
    int loopcount = 0;
    int count = 0;

    while((i = fileReader.read())!=-1){
        char ch = (char)i;
        fileContents = fileContents + ch;
    }
    char[] ch=fileContents.toCharArray();

    for(int n = 0; n < ch.length; n++) {
        boolean addCharacter=true;
        for(int t = 0; t < n; t++) {
            if (ch[n] == (fileContents.charAt(t)))
            addCharacter=false;
            }
            if (addCharacter) {
                for(int j = 0; j < fileContents.length(); j++) {
                    if(ch[n]==fileContents.charAt(j))
                    count=count+1;
                }
                Arrays.sort(ch);
                System.out.print(ch[n] + ": "+(count));
                System.out.println();
                count=0;
                loopcount++;
            }
    }

}   
}
```

The output is supposed to be all the characters in the text, counted and sorted, however this is the result:

: 3339

X: 4

X: 4

X: 4

X: 4

[: 2

]: 2

If I // Arrays.sort() then I get all the characters in the text file counted correctly, however they are neither sorted or in descending order!

Comment: Why are you calling `Arrays.sort()` in a loop?

Comment: Mistake. I moved it up to where I pass fileContents to a char array, but there's no difference

Comment: This whole code is really weird. What is the purpose of that `while` loop? If you just want to read the file, than use `BufferedReader`.`readLine()` instead. Also the `if (addCharacter)` block should be outside of that `for(int t = 0; t < n; t++)` loop. You want to test first and add the character later. It would be much easier if you use a map to store the current counters. Would be a `Map<Character, Integer> charCounter` field with the following loop (pseudo code): `for every character in "ch": charCounter.put(char, charCounter.get(char) + 1)`.

Answer (score 0):

Your for-loop really doesnot make sense to me but if you want to read string from a file convert it to charArray and sort it you can do it this way

```
FileReader fileReader = new FileReader("yourFile.txt");
StringBuilder br = new StringBuilder();
while(true){
    int ch = fileReader.read();
    if(ch==-1)
        break;
    char chArr = (char)ch;
    br.append(chArr);
}
char[] ch=br.toString().replaceAll("\\s+", "").toCharArray(); //removed all spaces
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ch));
Arrays.sort(ch);
System.out.println("After sorting : "+Arrays.toString(ch)); // ascending order
for(int i = ch.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) 
      System.out.println(arr[i]);                          //descending order
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code had a lot of mistakes, including conceptual ones; so instead of getting into detailed explanations on how it could be corrected, I submit code which works and which I tried to make as similar to yours:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
  final String fileContents;
  try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("file.txt"))) {
    fileContents = sc.useDelimiter("\\Z").next();
  }
  final char[] ch = fileContents.toCharArray();
  Arrays.sort(ch);
  int prevChar = -1, count = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < ch.length; i++) {
    if (ch[i] != prevChar) {
      if (count > 0) System.out.println((char)prevChar + ": "+count);
      count = 1;
      prevChar = ch[i];
    } else count++;
  }
  if (count > 0) System.out.println((char)prevChar + ": "+count);
}
```

Note that I took the liberty to completely change the routine to load the whole file as a String. This is because I regard file reading as a side concern here.

The loop works by going through the sorted array and emitting count each time it encounters a character different from the previous one. In the end we have a duplicated line of code which prints the final character.